# Does a ConPTY reading pipe get notified on process termination?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, win32-process

So I am reading from a pipe which is connected to a PseudoConsole (ConPTY) and when process is done I want to stop.
In linux we get a `EOF` in such situation but in win32 we don't get any indication as I understand.

But what's the workaround ?

- Check if process is still alive doesn't work because of synchronisation issue.

Similar issue on github https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/329

A pseudo code of an issue

```rust
fn main() {
    let proc = conpty::spawn("ping").unwrap();
    let mut reader = proc.output().unwrap();

    loop {
        let mut buf = [0; 1028];
        // We will block here eventually.
        // But how to not BLOCK when process is gone
        let n = reader.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: From [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile#pipes): *"If an anonymous pipe is being used and the write handle has been closed, when ReadFile attempts to read using the pipe's corresponding read handle, the function returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`."*

Comment: Exactly @IInspectable I would love it to work this way.
But it doesn't :(

As I understand because internally ConPTY holds write handle until we call `ClosePseudoTerminal`. And I verified it as I remember. When we do close manually we will get this error.

Appreciate your comment